# Bad http request error

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am trying to call API parameters dynamically. Below is the code

```
   <?php
   $apikey="<API_KEY>";
   $senderid="TESTIN";
   $channel=2;
   $dcs=0; 
   $flashsms=0;
   $number="9171276664,678785612";
   $text="Hello Testing message dynamically";
   $route="11";

   $ch=curl_init("https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=".$apikey.'&senderid='.$senderid.'&channel='.$channel.'&DCS='.$dcs.'&flashsms='.$flashsms.'&number='.$number.'&text='.$text.'&route='.$route);
   ?>
```

It is throwing bad http request error!!!

Comment: You may want to `URLEncode` your parameters...

Comment: either some parameter is missing or you have to encode your url

Comment: @user2179026 Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: [UrlEncode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) just use it on all parameters

Comment: Did you provide the requested login data also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to urlencode every char, you can also use http build query to make it more readable : then can you send the errors you have if you still have one ?

```
<?php
   $params = Array(
      'apikey' => "xx",
      'senderid' => "TESTIN",
      'channel' => 2,
      'dcs' => 0,
      'flashsms' => 0,
      'number' => "1234,4567",
      'text' => "Hello Testing message dynamically",
      'route' => "11"
   ) ;

   $url = 'https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?'.http_build_query($params) ;

   $ch=curl_init($url) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all symbols is allowed in the url (e.g.: ';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=', '&' and space), so you should use the urlencode function for your parameters.

```
<?php
...
$number=urlencode("xxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxx");
$text=urlencode("Hello Testing message dynamically");
...

$ch=curl_init("https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=".$apikey.'&senderid='.$senderid.'&channel='.$channel.'&DCS='.$dcs.'&flashsms='.$flashsms.'&number='.$number.'&text='.$text.'&route='.$route);
?>
```